# number formatting in asp.net markup code?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have used almost all ways to format numbers in asp.net markup code,
I have used the below ways and none of them worked with me :

```
 <%# String.Format("{0:C}", Eval("Netprofit") ) %>
 <%# string.Format("{0:#,###}",  Eval("Netprofit").ToString()) %> ,
 <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Netprofit", "{0:#,###}") %> ,
 <%# string.Format((new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US")).NumberFormat, "{0:#,###}", Eval("Assets","{0:#,###}").ToString()) %>
 <%# string.Format("{0:C2}",  Eval("Netprofit").ToString()) %> ,
 <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Netprofit", "{0:C2}") %> ,
 <%# string.Format((new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US")).NumberFormat, "{0:C2}", Eval("Assets","{0:C2}").ToString()) %>
```

any other suggestions I need to make the number: (908934) looks like: (908,934)

Comment: You could try `N0` (`{0:N0}`).

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings

Comment: ((float)Eval("Netprofit")).toString("0.00");  or whatever format you need.  There's a format specifying for currency that you can use too.  Or if the type isn't float, use decimal or whatever as appropriate.  the main issue is that you're trying to format a number already cast to a string in most of your examples.

Comment: @AccessDenied already tired most of them , and no one of them works , there must be an issue with Eval

Comment: @Phill this can not be implemented with mark up code

Comment: @MartinCostello Tried this one also , and no results :(

Comment: @HAJJAJ could you add more context to your question please, are you using this code within a grid control, a repeater?  I've cast results from Eval many times with success, you can also create a function in the code behind to format the value for you, or even create a custom DataSource select statement and format the data inline that way.

Comment: Thanks Phill it works now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I had to convert the string to Decimal first then it works :

```
<%# string.Format(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"), "{0:N0}",  Convert.ToDecimal(Eval("Assets"))) %>
```

Thanks, everyone, I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

"N0" in "en-US" culture is what you need.

```
<%#string.Format(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"),"{0:N0}",Eval("Netprofit")) %>
```

Take a look at [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings).

> 1234.567 ("N", en-US) -> 1,234.57

Comment: Tried it and did not work :( 
<%# string.Format((new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US")).NumberFormat, "{0:0:N0}", Eval("Netprofit","{0:0:N0}").ToString()) %>

Comment: @HAJJAJ string format should not format string it should format number. Use {0:N0} format, not the one you displayed above.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

asp:BoundField HeaderText="Your Header" DataField="Some Numbers"                                                              DataFormatString="{0:0,0.00}"
//Edit the format according to your need

Comment: it is a list view not gridview